# Limite mínimo e máximo de um número em um input do tipo number

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Olá, gostaria de saber como posso colocar um limite, um número mínimo e máximo que poderá ser digitado no campo. Por exemplo, fazer com que o número digitado no campo abaixo não possa ser menor do que 0 e maior do que 9.

Obs: apenas números inteiros de 0 a 9.

```
<input type="number" id="nota" name="nota" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Só pode conter um número de 1 a 9, isso?

Comment: sim, isso mesmo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode utilizar os atributos `min` e `max` caso esteja usando `HTML5`

```html
<input type="number" min="1" max="10">
```

Comment: bah, isso mesmo. Eu ia dizer que o usuário  continua podendo digitar qualquer número, mas na hora do submit ele da o aviso. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Sim, kkk por nada @RaylanSoares. Se a resposta te ajudou marque-a como correta para que possa ajudar outros usuários com o mesmo problema.

Comment: @Techies min e max são atributos do html5, seria justo informar a sua compatibilidade: http://caniuse.com/#search=min

Comment: @Highlander  eu já ia pesquisar se funcionava em outras versões rs, valeu pelo comentário.

Comment: Estava esperando o tempo mínimo para marcar como correta =) @Techies

Comment: Adicionei a tag HTML5 pra facilitar outros usuários tbm @Highlander

Comment: Tranquilo @RaylanSoares. Boa sorte nos estudos.